# Java Tookit Screen Resolution - How can I use it?

Tags: java, toolkit

When using `int resolution = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenResolution();` to get my monitor's resolution, the integer `resolution` returns 96. What does this mean, how could it be used, and, if possible, could I get the resolution in a 4:3, 16:9, etc. format?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken that's the dpi (dots per inch). All this `4:3` is, is the screen width/height ratio, has nothing to do with resolution. How many dots per inch, the resolution. The higher the dpi, the higher (or more detailed) the resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`getScreenResolution()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getScreenResolution%28%29) return dots-per-inch (DPI). If you want the size of the screen, just use [`getScreenSize()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getScreenSize%28%29).

Here's a quote that gets you the basic idea of DPI vs. pixels:

> So, if you have a 600 pixel x 600 pixel image at 300DPI, it will output at 2 inches square. If you change this images DPI to 150, this will mean it will output at 4 inches square. So, as you can see, changing the DPI of an image changes it output size.

You can find rest of the explanation [here](http://photoshopninja.com/photoshop-top-tips/image-resolution-and-dpi-explained/).

Comment: I feel stupid for not thinking of that. I understand DPI and resolution, it just had to leave my head at the time. Thanks.