# How to change device screen resolution with java?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I working on project with frame size 1024×768 I want to change the system resolution to become like project one when my app starts..

Comment: Please check this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48544238/set-resolution-manually-in-java-swing

Comment: Thanks for the response but the answer of that question can't solve what I'm looking for.